# How do I specify a UITextField to show/hide the keyboard to in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to move the view whenever a user tries to enter a text at the bottom, but I could not specify the bottom textField.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)


 @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
 if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
    if (self.view.frame.origin.y == 0){
         self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
     }
 }
```

}

```
@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
 if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
     self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice library to handle such movement of text input fields in iOS. Please check https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager. It might be far easy to deal with such issues on every screen of your iOS app with a single liner solution.